# JSP equivalent to ASP Request.Files

Tags: jsp, file-upload

This is what I've done in ASP:

On the form:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   ...
   <asp:Button ID="cmdGetFileToUpload" runat="server" Text="Send File" />
   ...
   <asp:Panel id=divUploadFile Visible="False" ...>
      <input id="inpUploadFile" runat="server" name="inpUploadFile" type="file" />
      <asp:Button ID="cmdUploadFile" runat="server" Text="Upload File" />
   </asp:Panel
   ...
</form>
```

In the code behind:

```
Protected Sub cmdGetFileToUpload_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdGetFileToUpload.Click
   'This shows the upload file panel when the user clicks the Send Files button
   Me.divUploadFile.Visible = True

   ... hide other panels
End Sub

Protected Sub cmdUploadFile_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdUploadFile.Click
   Dim oFile As HttpPostedFile
   Dim sFullPathName as String
   Dim sFileName as String

   oFile = Request.Files(0)
   If oFile.FileName <> "" Then
      sFullPathName = oFile.FileName
      sFileName = sFullPathName.Substring(sFullPathName.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
      oFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(".\myFolder\") & sFileName)
   End If

   ... do stuff with the file
End Sub
```

I've downloaded commons-fileupload.jar and its dependancies and have them in my project.  But it's not clear to me where the code is to be placed.  I have a class method I call when setting up my page after post back so put it in there, but servletfileupload.ismultipartcontent(request) always returns false.  The documentation says that's normally because the request has already been processed.  So, I moved the code to the top of my form as follows:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
    import="myClasses.myClass,
        org.apache.commons.fileupload.*,
        org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*,
        org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*,
        org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*,
        java.io.*, java.util.*"
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>MyPageTile</title>
    <style>
        ... various styles
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ... various scripts
    </script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:tan;" onload="window.history.forward();" >
    <%@ include file="subforms/my_banner.jsp" %>

<%  if (session.getAttribute("user")==null) { response.sendRedirect("index.jsp"); } 
    else {
        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
        if (isMultipart) {
            DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            ServletContext servletContext = this.getServletConfig().getServletContext();
            File repository = (File) servletContext.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");
            factory.setRepository(repository);
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = iter.next();
                if ( ! item.isFormField() ) {
                    File uploadedFile = new File( "/uploads/" + session.getAttribute("user") + ".xlsm");
                    item.write(uploadedFile);
                }
            }
        }
... other stuff then my form
<form id="AdminForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

However, once again servletfileupload.ismultipartcontent(request) returns false.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue - my form tag didn't have the **method** attibute set to **post**.  I still have debugging to do, but I'm at least past this hurdle.  Hopefully this will be useful to someone else.